# Rollup Build seems to be overly large for component library

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs

I am using rollup (v2.13.1), and it all works fine exporting out my React Library, BUT, I believe that I am using the WHOLE library in my vendor js file and NOT just the components I am using.
The library seems a bit large when I run tool analyze. Seems I'm not properly doing modules, or ?

package.json build command: "build": "rollup -c",

Here is my Rollup config, anything I am missing or doing incorrectly?

```
And I am using it in a seperate application like so:
import { Button, Icon } from "myReactLibrary";
```

CODE: Rollup Config

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      dir: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
     dir: packageJson.module,
     format: 'esm',
     sourcemap: true,
   },
],
 plugins: [
   peerDepsExternal(),
   typescript({useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true}),
   resolve(),
   commonjs(),
   postcss({
    modules: true,
   }),
  copy({
    targets: [
      {
        src: 'src/styles/colors.scss',
        dest: 'build',
        rename: 'colors.scss',
      },
    {
      src: 'src/styles/helpers.scss',
      dest: 'build',
      rename: 'helpers.scss',
    },
    {
      src: 'src/styles/mixins.scss',
      dest: 'build',
      rename: 'mixins.scss',
    },
  ],
}),
 ],
};
```

And the "src/index.ts" file is:

```
  import Accordion from './Accordion/Accordion';
  import AccordionGroup from './Accordion/AccordionGroup';
  import Avatar from './Avatar/Avatar';
  import Button, {BUTTON_THEMES} from './Button/Button';
  import Checkbox from './Checkbox/Checkbox';
  import CheckboxGroup from './Checkbox/CheckboxGroup';
  import Form from './Form/Form';
  import {Size as ELEMENT_SIZE} from './base.types';
  import Grid, {BREAKPOINTS} from './Grid/Grid';
  import Icon from './Icon/Icon';
  import InputField from './Input/Input';
  import {LoaderComponent, LoaderPage} from './Loaders/Loaders';
  import Modal from './Modal/Modal';
  import Panel from './Panel/Panel';
  import PlainModal from './PlainModal/PlainModal';
  import Radio from './Radio/Radio';
   import RadioGroup from './Radio/RadioGroup';
  import SelectField from './SelectField/SelectField';
  import {SelectOptions, SelectArrayOptions, SelectBaseOption, SelectGroupOptions} from   './SelectField/SelectField.types';
  import TextArea from './TextArea/TextArea';
  import {Label, ErrorMessage} from './Parts';

 export {
    Accordion,
    AccordionGroup,
    Avatar,
    Button,
    BUTTON_THEMES,
    Checkbox,
    CheckboxGroup,
    ELEMENT_SIZE,
    ErrorMessage,
    Form,
    Grid,
    BREAKPOINTS,
    Icon,
    InputField,
    Label,
    LoaderComponent,
    LoaderPage,
    Modal,
    Panel,
    PlainModal,
    Radio,
    RadioGroup,
    SelectField,
    SelectOptions,
    SelectArrayOptions,
    SelectBaseOption,
    SelectGroupOptions,
    TextArea,
  };
```

Comment: I use a similar structure for my library, and find it too big, did you managed to solve your issue ?

Comment: I added terser plugin to bring it down further, but not a big difference update. You didn't find any solutions?

Comment: I found a solution, added an answer below

Comment: I noticed you also have a single Icon component, how do you set an icon with it ? I used an object with all my icons paths, but noticed it was pretty big (300kb), and it was imported entirely each time I used an icon

Comment: We use custom icons/svg's, so we just need to pass in the "name" and reference it with className.. as our svg's are in iconmoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rollup option `preserveModules` in your output configurations:

```
output: [
    {
      dir: packageJson.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
      preserveModules: true,
    },
    {
     dir: packageJson.module,
     format: 'esm',
     sourcemap: true,
     preserveModules: true,
   },
```

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules

Comment: Hey, so i have tried this but when trying to import each component from libary you need to do something like this 'import from '@library/dist/cjs/components/Component'

Comment: @ArsenCenko you get that working? It didn't work for me. Still large bundle size.